# Parsing ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: android-studio, parsing, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists of types String and Int.

```
ArrayList<String> numbersInString=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<>();
```

`numbersInString` contains two items as follows:

```
numberInString.add("1");
numberInString.add("2");
```

Now, What my problem is I want the items `1` and `2` to be added into `numbers` as Integers from `numbersInString` *(So that I can perform arithmetic operations in my work)*. **Is there any straight way to parse all items at a time rather than parsing all items one by one ?**

Someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

```java
List<String> numberInString = new ArrayList<>();
numberInString.add("1");
numberInString.add("2");
List<Integer> numbers= numberInString.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
numbers.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Please post a well maintained answer.

Comment: The answer Is there a problem?